# MongoDB C++ driver can't read int32 value, expects k_int32

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm new to C++ and MongoDB C++ driver. I'm trying to retrieve an element from a `bsoncxx::document` which is stored as `int32` in the database. However, when I try to get the value using `mongocxx` driver, it expects the type to be `k_int32` and throws off a compilation error.

**Code**

```
 void iterate_over_docs() {
      mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find({});
      for (auto doc : cursor) {
        bsoncxx::document::element active_elem = doc["active"];
        std::string type1 =  bsoncxx::to_string(active_elem.type());
        std::cout << type1 << std::endl; // this prints int32

        auto active = date_elem.get_int32(); // line of error

        break;
      }
```

**Output**

```
$ make run
int32
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'bsoncxx::v_noabi::exception'
  what():  expected element type k_int32
make: *** [Makefile:21: run] Aborted
```

How can I have `mongocxx` accept `int32` value instead of `k_int32`? Once I retrieve this value, I'd like to create a vector of `int`s. Right now, I can't even use `.get_int32` method because if expects `k_int32`.

[Relevant `mongocxx` API documentation](http://mongocxx.org/api/current/classbsoncxx_1_1document_1_1element.html#ae12fc72490c7bebb145a1fefe5e0898e)

Comment: In your code `active_elem ` type is `int32` but yo tried to get `date_elem` as `int32`. I suggest to write getter function for any type like this:
```
auto get_value = [&](const bsoncxx::document::element& e)
{ 
    switch(e.type())
{
    case bsoncxx::type::k_int32:
        return e.get_int32();
    case ...
}
};

auto active_value = get_value(active_elem); // use this value

```

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. The getter function is a great idea.